# How to sanitize sql fragment in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sanitization

I have to sanitize a part of sql query. I can do something like this:

```
class << ActiveRecord::Base
  public :sanitize_sql
end

str = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql(["AND column1 = ?", "two's"], '')
```

But it is not safe because I expose protected method. What is a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context?  `sanitize_sql` and friends are often called inside AR::Base-derived classes, without needing to alter visibility

Comment: That is a good and valid point. I just cringe when I use someone's private or protected methods.

Answer (score 58):

You can just use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize_sql(string)
```

Comment: This delegates to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote` (at least in Rails 4)

Comment: Deprecated. New sanitization methods [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html). See Bryan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608331/165673)

Comment: I updated this answer from the deprecated version (`sanitize`) to the current working version as of Rails 6 (`sanitize_sql`). If someone wants a full explanation of all the sanitization methods, I'd suggest [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: I get an error message: private method `sanitize_sql' called for ActiveRecord::Base:Class

Answer (score 18):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote` does the trick in Rails 3.x

Answer (score 18):

This question does not specify that the answer has to come from `ActiveRecord` nor does it specify for which version of Rails it should be. For that reason (and because it is one of the top and few) answers on how to sanitize parameters in Rails...

---

Here a solution that works with Rails 4:

In `ActiveRecord::Sanitization::ClassMethods` you have **sanitize_sql_for_conditions** and its two other *aliases*:
 **sanitize_conditions** and **sanitize_sql**. The three do literally the exact same thing.

`sanitize_sql_for_conditions`

> Accepts an array, hash, or string of SQL conditions and sanitizes
>   them into a valid SQL fragment **for a WHERE clause**.

Also in ActiveRecord you have

`sanitize_sql_for_assignment` which

> Accepts an array, hash, or string of SQL conditions and sanitizes them
>   into a valid SQL fragment **for a SET clause**.

- The methods above are included in ActiveRecord::Base by default and **therefore are included in any ActiveRecord model**.

See [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html)

---

Also, however, in ActionController you have `ActionController::Parameters` which allows you to

> choose which attributes should be whitelisted for mass updating and
>   thus prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed.
>   Provides two methods for this purpose: **require** and **permit**.

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: { name: 'Bryan', age: 21 })
req  = params.require(:user) # will throw exception if user not present
opt  = params.permit(:name)  # name parameter is optional, returns nil if not present
user = params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age) # user hash is required while `name` and `age` keys are optional
```

The "Parameters magic" is called Strong Parameters ([docs here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#strong-parameters)) and you can use that to sanitize parameters in a controller before sending it to a model.

- The methods above are included by default in `ActionController::Base` and **therefore are included in any Rails controller**.

I hope that helps anyone, if only to learn and demystify Rails! :)

Comment: Does `require` and `permit` sanitize parameters against SQL injection, or just validate their presence?

Comment: it does zero sanitizing, just validates presence

Comment: @Matt: Jimmy is correct, `require` and `permit` don't do any sanitizing by themselves. But `ActionController::Parameters.new` does the sanitizing, so all of your controllers should already be sanitizing all parameters. I'll update my answer later when I have time because I also found this very cool gem called rails-html-sanitizer https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I'm in a situation where I'm sending a large amount of JSON to my controller, and am dealing with 3s+ response times. I was able to decrease these to 2s by eliminating redundancy in my JSON, and further get it down to below 500ms by not instantiating an ActiveRecord object. Just wanted to be sure that I was exposing a security risk!

Comment: Note that the sanitization methods above are protected class methods, so you'll either need to call them from within your AR class or expose them via a public class method in your own AR class.

Comment: None of the current crop of sanitization methods correctly handle nil attributes as WHERE conditions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53948845/165673)

Answer (score 11):

As of rails 5 the recomended way is to use: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(string)`

as stated here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28947

`ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(string)` is deprecated

Comment: Not the recommended. Use the sanitation apis in Bryan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608331/165673) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when it comes to sanitizing SQL WHERE conditions, the best solution *was* [sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions), because it correctly handled NULL conditions (e.g. would generate `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL` if a nil attribute was passed).

For some reason, it was deprecated in Rails 5. So I rolled a future-proofed version, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53948665/165673