# Sanitizing SQL in Rails where conditions may be NULL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sanitization

I'm struggling to sanitize a raw SQL query in which the WHERE conditions may either have a value or be NULL. I was hoping to use Active Record's built-in sanitizers...

(**NOTE:** I'll be using a *simplified* query for demo purposes- our real one is a complex UNION across different model types that would be hard to do with the AR query interface)

**Try 1:**

```
raw_query = "SELECT * FROM folders WHERE user_id = ? AND parent_id = ?"
sanitized_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [raw_query, current_user.id, params[:parent_id]])
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sanitized_query);
```

But if `params[:parent_id]` is nil, then `sanitized_query` ends up as
`SELECT * FROM folders WHERE user_id = 1 AND parent_id = NULL`
Which isn't valid, as `parent_id = NULL` should be `parent_id IS NULL`

**Try 2:**

I then found the [sanitize_sql_hash](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_hash) method, which seemed perfect for building the condition:

```
sanitized_conditions = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_hash, {user_id: current_user.id, parent_id: params[:parent_id]})
sanitized_query = "SELECT * FROM folders WHERE #{sanitized_conditions}"
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sanitized_query);
```

But the first line fails with:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `abstract_class?' for Object:Class

The method is also listed as deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5, but it's exactly what I'm looking for. Is there another way to generate a safe WHERE condition from a hash of values?

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145645/rails-how-to-sanitize-sql-in-find-by-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is being thrown in the `reset_table_name` method at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7bb620869725ad6de603f6a5393ee17df13aa96c/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L160 so maybe this method is not designed to work on the ActiveRecord::Base class.

Assuming you have got a model class for Folder this should work:

```
Folder.send(:sanitize_sql_hash, {user_id: current_user.id, parent_id: params[:parent_id]})
```

In a quick test I got something like:

```
'"folders"."user_id" = 123 AND "folders"."parent_id" IS NULL'
```

Comment: Thanks, this *does* work for now- annoying that `sanitize_sql_hash` is being removed in Rails 5 though, meaning we can't use this as a permanent solution...

Comment: Yes upgrading to Rails 5 will be interesting. Maybe there will be a better option then, otherwise the only option I can think of is use the `to_sql` method to generate a whole query and then extract the where clause, something like `Folder.where(...).to_sql.split('WHERE ')[1]`

Comment: @Steve- yeah, extracting the where clause from the generated query is actually not a bad idea- thanks for the help!

Comment: I created a monkey patch for the where clause extraction: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53948665/165673)

Answer (score 1):

I created a Rails 5-safe version of the deprecated but much needed  [sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions), using @Steve's [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001762/sanitizing-sql-in-rails-where-conditions-may-be-null#comment44394056_28002097):

```
class ActiveRecord::Base 

  # Sanitizes a hash of attribute/value pairs into SQL conditions for a WHERE clause.
  #
  # (This is an alternative to sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions, which was deprecated in Rails 5.
  # SEE: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions)
  # 
  # This is needed because the latest SQL sanitization methods cannot handle conditions where an attribute is nil.

  def self.sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions_alt(attrs)
    self.where(attrs).to_sql.split('WHERE ')[1]
  end

end
```

Call it on whatever AR model class represents the table you're targeting (not on ActiveRecord::Base directly).

> Folder.sanitize_sql_hash_for_conditions_alt({user_id: 1, parent_id:
>   nil})
>   => "\"folders\".\"user_id\" = 1 AND \"folders\".\"parent_id\" IS NULL"